# GitHubコードで「.」を含む文字を検索したいのですが、You can't use the following wildcard characters as part of your search query

Tags: github

**GitHubコードで「.」を含む文字を検索したいです**
・具体的には「m.with」
・実際に試すと、[警告が表示されます](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/#considerations-for-code-search)

> You can't use the following wildcard characters as part of your search
>   query: . , : ; / \ ` ' " = * ! ? # $ & + ^ | ~ < > ( ) { } [ ]. The
>   search will simply ignore these symbols.

---

**\でエスケープしても駄目でした**

```
m\.with
```

---

**質問**
・検索できないということでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

検索できないと思われます。

### GitHubのヘルプより

> You can't use the following wildcard characters as part of your search
>   query: . , : ; / \ ` ' " = * ! ? # $ & + ^ | ~ < > ( ) { } [ ]. The
>   search will simply ignore these symbols.

これはつまり、

> 以下の文字を検索することはできません。
>   . , : ; / \ ` ' " = * ! ? # $ & + ^ | ~ < > ( ) { } [ ]
>   この文字が含まれている場合、この文字を無視して検索します。

的な意味だと思います。
**参考:**
[Escaping characters in GitHub code search - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34242460/6366398)
[searching code(GitHub Help)](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/#considerations-for-code-search)

Comment: もしかしたら何か裏技的な方法があるかも、と期待したのですが…。仕様なら仕方がないため諦めます